# After upgrading to unity 5.4 Substance crash after building for iOS and goes missing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, substance

I am experiencing yet another weird one. After upgrading from unity 5.3.6f1 to unity 5.4.0f3 every time i open a my project it crashes(if the substance is not included it doesnt crash only when i build the project). it then breaks the substance, they are stuck in generating state. After fixing the substance and then building the project for iOS platform the crash happens during the build process and the substance breaks in the build, in other words the substance is completely broken and all references are missing. i created a unlisted video here that you can see what i mean, **[Check out the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmsSEdsTCRc)** Crazy right?
I've tried reproducing the error with a new project but it works fine when i build. so I'm wondering if it hasn't got anything to do with actually upgrading from the previous version.

Can anyone share any light on this?

Thanks in advance

P.S. here is the code it spits out just before it breaks the substance.

```
 material->IsFlagEnabled (ProceduralMaterial::Flag_Clone) || m_PingedMaterial == NULL || m_PingedMaterial == material
 UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was a bug. and the Allegorithmic team and Unity team got it fixed so quickly. The version with the fix is Unity 5.5b6, I've tested it and it works 100%

```
Substance: Fixed crash when selecting a ProceduralMaterial after switching build platform. (820301)
Substance: Fixed occasional ProceduralMaterial asset import crash. (822217)
Substance: Fixed SubstanceImporter.ExportBitmaps generated file names.
```